# I want to access the SSH on my college's LAN but right now I am at home so I am not connected to its network

Tags: 12.04, ssh, openssh

I used to connect to my college's server via the command

```
ssh user-profile@server-ip-address
```

Now I returned home and am unfortunately no longer connected to the network. When I try the same command that I used to give (the above one) it just keeps on showing that its trying to connect but it doesnt.

How can I access my user profile on the college's server sitting at my home pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not any more in a LAN, but in the internet WAN, that's the reason why you can't connect. Obtain the **external** IP of your college server and issue the same command with the external (also called **public** IP).
To obtain the public IP (it *should* be a static IP that don't change) visit [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) or any equivalent web site from the school's LAN, or ask support to the school's technician.
Remember that if the school's connection device (typically a router) has the SSH door closed you **will not** be able to connect. There are various methods to pass through an hardware firewall, but this isn't the right place to talk about it, because it's not legal.
Have a nice day.

Comment: The institution might use a pool of IPs. Having one external IP won't be of any help unless there is a [jump server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server) to get to the internal host. We don't know the type of firewall. The reason he can't reach the host have nothing to do to any legal stuff.